# Vue resets child Component data on props update

Tags: vue.js

I have child component, that has some internal data, that should not be changed from outside. But when I update prop from parent component, this internal data is reset.

Basically in example below, when we change `title` from outside, `value` is set back to empty ''. How can I make `value` persistent with Child component props update?

> Child.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="child">
    <h2>{{title}}</h2>
    <input type="text" :value="value" v-on:change="$emit('change', $event.target.value)">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      title: {
        default: 'Just title'
      }
    },
    data() {
      return {
        value: ''
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

> Parent.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="parent">
    <Child :title="title" v-on:change="processTitle($event)"></Child>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Child from './Child';

  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        title: 'Title from parent'
      }
    },
    methods: {
      processTitle(value) {
        this.title = value.reverse();
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not setting the `value` data attribute, `:value=value` means that "if value changes, the input value should pick up that change". But `value` doesn't change. Use `v-model` instead if you want to keep it simple.

```js
Vue.component("Child", {
  props: {
    title: {
      default: 'Just title'
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      value: ''
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div class="child">
      <h2>{{title}}</h2>
      <input type="text" v-model="value" v-on:change="$emit('change', $event.target.value)">
    </div>
  `
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      title: 'Title from parent'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    processTitle(value) {
      this.title = value.split("").reverse().join("");
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div class="parent">
      <child :title="title" v-on:change="processTitle($event)"></child>
    </div>
  `
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

### EDIT

Also, if you want a continuous effect, don't use `@change` - use `@input` instead:

```js
Vue.component("Child", {
  props: {
    title: {
      default: 'Just title'
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      value: ''
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div class="child">
      <h2>{{title}}</h2>
      <input type="text" v-model="value" v-on:input="$emit('change', $event.target.value)">
    </div>
  `
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      title: 'Title from parent'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    processTitle(value) {
      this.title = value.split("").reverse().join("");
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div class="parent">
      <child :title="title" v-on:change="processTitle($event)"></child>
    </div>
  `
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```